# scrollbar не отображается в ie на windows mobile 8.1

Tags: html, css

В элементе **div** находится элемент **ul**, элемент **ul** шире чем элемент **div** и выходит за его пределы, свойство *overflow* для **div** выставлено, во всех браузерах scrollbar отображается, кроме ie на windows mobile 8.1. Подскажите, может  кто сталкивался с данной проблемой.
[`Тут`](https://jsfiddle.net/6y5xun0r/6/) пример того что нужно, там дополнительные селекторы с префиксами для других браузеров в которых работает.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn736066(v=vs.85).aspx  вот тут можешь посмотреть, может префиксы или же еще какая-то хрень

Comment: пробовал добавлять и префикс -ms-overflow-style: scrollbar;
не помогло

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13996387/div-overflow-scrolling-when-ms-viewport-is-specified вот

Comment: я попробовал как там советуют https://jsfiddle.net/6y5xun0r/12/, но всё равно нету scrollbar'a

Answer (score 0):

Я предполагаю, что вы указали размеры в статичных единицах - пикселях (как в указанном примере). Примените "*резиновую/жидкую*" разметку для стилей, например width:40%. Если всё-же требуется статичная величина, то я рекомендую вам применять **em** вместо **px**. **[Конвертор](http://pxtoem.com/)**.

Comment: уж лучше тогда rem